# Babilonic notation to decimal notation. Example $1;12 \cdot 15$

Tags: change-of-basis

I'm currently working in a program that convert numbers in babilonic notation into decimal numbers. The problem I have is that the example and requirements described by the teacher deliver numbers in the following format

$$1;12 \cdot 15$$

That would be a number on its "babilonic" structure. The result after some operations that I trully don't know and were shown by the teacher really fast seems like $72,25$ in decimal notation.

That was the example provided and I'm not too clear about it. I've found something similar in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal#Examples) referring to calculation of irrational numbers starting from a sexagesimal structure similar to the one provided but I've found is not the same.

I hope somebody has any information about babilonic numbers and the notation provided because further than Wikipedia I haven't found something closer to my problem, any hint or help will be really appreciated.

Comment: If your $1;12 \cdot 15$ is supposed to represent $1 \times 60^1+12 \times 60^{0}+15\times 60^{-1}$ then that is clearly $72.25$ in decimal, i.e. $7 \times 10^1 + 2 \times 10^0+2\times 10^{-1}+5 \times 10^{-2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume the ";" separates base-60 digits, and the "$\cdot$" is the analog of a decimal point, so $1;12\cdot 15$ stands for $1 \times 60 + 12 + 15/60$, which indeed is $72.25$ in decimal notation.  More generally,
$$ a_k; a_{k-1}; \ldots ; a_0 \cdot a_{-1} ; a_{-2}; \ldots a_{-m}  = \sum_{j=-m}^{k}  60^j\; a_j$$
where $0 \le a_j \le 59$.